# Variable lost after dismissing modalViewController

Tags: ipad, properties, modalviewcontroller

I'm using Reachability in my iPad app and discovered some issues when using modalViewControllers.

In my mainViewController I have a BOOL variable determining weather I'm online or not. Here's my code:

```
// mainViewController.h
BOOL online;

// mainViewController.m
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if([[note object] isReachable]) {
        online = YES;
    }
    else {
        online = NO;
    }
}
- (void)getOnline
{
    NSLog(@"%d", online);
}

// modalViewController.m
#import "mainViewController.h"

- (IBAction)dismissMe
{
    mainViewController *main = [[mainViewController alloc] init];
    [main getOnline];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I'm calling `[self getOnline]` within the mainViewController, it returns 1 ('cause I **am** online).

**But:** when I'm calling [main getOnline] within the modalViewController, it returns 0 in the log.

Does anybody know why?!

I also tried to put the `online` variable as a `@property` into the modalViewController to handle the *if online stuff* within the modal. But when I assign a value to it (from the main), and log it within the modal, it always returns `(NULL)`.

Hope, you can help me! With best regards, Julian

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: because they use *different* instances of the `online` variable.

Long answer: you should only *declare* `BOOL online` in the header, not *define* it. Defining should happen in the .m file, like this:

In the mainViewController.h:

```
extern BOOL online; // Declare the variable
```

In the mainViewController.m:

```
BOOL online; // Define the variable

// the rest of your code
```

The way your code is written, a separate `BOOL online` is created for each .m file that includes `mainViewController.h`; I am sure this is *not* what you intended.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, thanks for short answer, thanks for long answer :) When I try to put `extern BOOL online` into my header, I just get _Type name does not allow storage class to be specified_.

Comment: So maybe I can **GET** the online status **FROM** the main... But I _never_ done getting a property from another class. Didn't ever work. How could I do this?

Comment: Okay. I just played around a bit. And what actually **DOES NOT** work: When I set a variable in my mainView, present the modalView and then dismiss it (go back to main), this variable, set in the main is not defined anymore!!

Comment: @Julian "I just get *Type name does not allow storage class to be specified.*" --> I did not realize that you are making your `online` an instance variable; I thought it was free-standing. You need to move `extern BOOL online` *outside* of your interface declaration (before the `@interface` or after the `@end` keyword in the header). Similarly, `BOOL online;` in the .m file needs to be outside of your `@implementation` block.